# CreateAtAction returns "No route matches the supplied values" in ASP.Net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, .net-core

I have the following Put Method to update my Item::

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("items")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateProduct([FromBody] CatalogItem productToUpdate)
{
       var catalogItem = await _catalogContext.CatalogItems.SingleOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == productToUpdate.Id);
       if (catalogItem == null) return NotFound(new { Message = $"Item with id {productToUpdate.Id} not found." });

       catalogItem = productToUpdate;
       _catalogContext.CatalogItems.Update(catalogItem);
       await _catalogContext.SaveChangesAsync();

       return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetItemById), new { id = productToUpdate.Id }, productToUpdate);
}
```

And the following GetItemBy Id Action:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("items/{id:int}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetItemById(int id)
{
       if (id <= 0)
       {
           return BadRequest();
       }
       var item = await _catalogContext.CatalogItems.SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == id);
       if (item != null)
       {

           return Ok(item);
       }
       return NotFound();
}
```

When I call the Update action via swagger with this object:

```
{
  "id": 42,
  "name": "TestProduct",
  "description": "this is a test",
  "price": 12.55,
  "imageFileName": null,
  "imagePath": null,
  "catalogTypeId": 1,
  "catalogBrandId": 2
}
```

I get this error:

> An unhandled exception was thrown by the application. catalogapi  |
>   System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied
>   values.

The item is updated in the database, but the error occurs when CreatedAtAction is executed. I have the same problem in my POST action. I tried to use CreatedAtRoute and even tried it without the third parameter productToUpdate. I can call the GetItemById (/api/Catalog/items/42) without any problem...

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: What happens if you change the Route on GetItemById to `[Route("{id:int}")]` removing `items/` part?

Comment: Thanks..this would work, is there a way i can tell the CreatedAtAction Method to include this "items". @MohsinMehmood Because it's a bit confusing when I use AtAction but the Route affects this

Comment: Oh I figured it out. With return CreatedAtAction("items", new { id = catalogItem.Id }); it worked. Alltough "index" is not the Action itself it still worked lol. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction..something was suspicious about that "index", but I need this since the GetItemsById should by accessible through this Route...

Answer (score 0):

Does the get work? If so, change the route on the put to the same as the get.

Comment: the get works like that: /api/Catalog/items/42. Should I use CreatedAtRoute or CreatedAtAction? An therefore, how should the route look like? Like so: CreatedAtRoute("/api/Catalog/items/", new { id = productToUpdate.Id })? @arjay-h